# Why are EM font sizes super tiny on Android mobile?

Tags: android, css, font-size

I'm using `em` for font sizes. Example:

```
body {
  font-size:16px;
}
h1 {
  font-size:2em;
}
@media (max-width:860) {
  body {
    font-size:0.8em;
  }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting super tiny fonts on Android mobile. What might be causing this? I haven't experienced this before.

### Screenshot

[image: Android Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your HTML and your CSS please? That way we can check the two more thoroughly, I have a couple of ideas but want to narrow it down before answering.

Comment: You can check the html / css here: www.now.ee

Comment: Does `font-size: 200%;` give you what you want instead? Might just be a bug in the browser.

Comment: Adding this to the `<head>` section resolved this for me: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `em` values for your `font-size`, it's based on the parent container, and not the `<body>`. Instead, you can use `rem` values, which stands for **root em**, where **root** is the `html` tag. So try the following:

### CSS

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
@media (max-width:860) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

> You can learn more about CSS units at [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: @user3615851 You'll need to post more information or code. From the code you've posted, and your website you've linked to, this solution should work. I've looked at your site, and it looks like you changed to `rem` values, and everything looks fine on Android / iOS.

Answer (score 5):

`em` is relative to the font size of its direct or nearest parent. That makes it vulnerable to dramatic changes if any of its direct parents have low/high values set for the `font-size` property.

Instead, you should use `rem` **(root *em*)** that's relative to the font size of the `<body>` element.

In order for your `font-size` property to apply correctly, you need to make sure you have the proper [`viewport settings`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) in `<head>`. Please note `<meta name="viewport" ... >` should be the first of your meta tags in order to apply on all devices (some ignore it if it's not first).

Comment: Hi, I changed em to rem and have the correct meta tag as first, although nothing changed. 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

Comment: In this case, you'll just have to find a way to inspect [`what's going on`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) your device and see what rules do apply and why it's so small.

Answer (score 1):

try using following tags in your header

```html
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```